# How to understand 'with' in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, meaning

> The vast majority of compound words are constructed from a headword
> and a prefix (ex-sailor, semi-detached, anti-hero ); a headword and a
> suffix (shoot-out, phone-in, crack-down ) or ***with*** two or more
> different parts of speech (two nouns = book-end;noun and verb =
> joy-ride;two verbs = dry-clean, etc).

Is 'The vast majority of compound words are constructed from with two or more different parts of speech' right?

Is it the same as 'From underneath the trees we watch the sky.'?

In the two sentences, 'from' precedes a preposition.

Comment: I think you are misparsing this. "Constructed" is followed by "from a headword and a prefix" and "with two or more different parts of speech", joined by "or".

Comment: Incidentally, I would dispute the author's assertion that _dry-clean_ is two verbs. Surely _dry_ here is an adjective (without using water)?

Comment: @Kate Bunting  Thanks for pointing out this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you quote the sentence, you omitted everything from the phrase"a headword" through and including "crack-down) or", giving the strange construction "constructed from with".  The correct way to interpret the whole sentence is, "constructed from... or constructed with...."  So it is not at all like "from underneath".